# A view component named 'XX' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using aspnet 5 and MVC 6.

I have created a view component using the instructions in  [HERE](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/view-components.html)  but when I run my website I get an error

A view component named 'XX' could not be found.
  AT

```
@Component.Invoke("XX"))
```

Here is the structure of my project

```
namespace Test
{
public class XXViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
   public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {       
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

Then in the views folder I have Views/Assets/index.cshtml

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Component.Invoke("XX"))
    </div>
</div>
```

The vc is in Views/Assets/Components/XX/default.cshtml

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="listOfCustomers">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <span> Test partial View</span>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am unable to repro the error that you are seeing...I used your exact code and it worked fine...I am using RC1 version.

Answer (score 14):

I've had a similar issue. 
What helped me was the bottom section on the page you used yourself ([Avoiding magic strings](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html#avoiding-magic-strings)):

- remove 'ViewComponent' suffix from the name of the class (and therefore the constructor) - you would then have:

  ```
  public class XX : ViewComponent
  ```
- to use `nameof` when invoking the view component:

  ```
  @Component.Invoke(nameof(XX))
  ```
- don't forget to use `using` of your view component in your main view (Views/Assets/index.cshtml) - in your case `@using Test`

This might both help you and keep the invoking of your component compile-time saved.

As Joe Audette pointed out, the views might be in an unusual location, but that would result in a different error message.

Comment: This is a great tip, and solved my issue as well

Answer (score 2):

What fixed the issue for me was to Clean and then Rebuild the solution. You might want to try this first before trying to change your files

Comment: I had this error when the solution had worked fine before. Apparently cleaning and rebuilding was all I needed to do as well.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question because I had a similar problem but where I want to dynamically load a particular view and needed to ensure that it exists before calling the View() method.
This will let you know if the view exists or not. Not fully related with the question though, but hopefully will help people sent by google :)

```
this.ViewEngine.FindView(this.ViewContext, "test", false).Success
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the namespace into your _ViewImports.cshtml?

```
@using Test
```

Comment: also I think the view needs to be under Views/Shared/Components/XX not under Views/Assets unless you have cusotmized the viewengine to look for it there

Comment: @JoeAudette not quite true - it is also fine to be in the folder /Views/{ControllerName}/Components (as per the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the namespace of the `ViewComponent` class, which was a different namespace than the calling Controller, and also different from the folder structure the actual `.cshtml` resides in.

| Not sure if this is a proper way to solve this, but it worked for me. Answer by @Drakir pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In csproj file I found that the cshtml file was added to <content remove ...> tag, removing the files from this tag solved it for me